# Writing Json string from SQL query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to create a json string inside "reader.Read()" how can I do that? This is for a API I'm creating so you can request the page for example api.ashx?tablename=CurrencySymbol&id=5 Hope someone can help

I would like to create json from column values from the database

** Lets not worry about the security of this, it's just for a internal application that only I will use **

```
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
    { 
        context.Response.Clear();

            string tablename = context.Request.QueryString["tablename"];
            int ID = Int32.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["ID"]);
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

            SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WorldViewDatabase"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader reader;

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + tablename "WHERE ID = " + ID;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

            sqlConnection1.Open();

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            // Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //context.Response.Write(reader);
            }
            sqlConnection1.Close();

            context.Response.Write(ID);
            context.Response.Write(tablename);
            return;
   }
```

Comment: is the json *stored in* the database? or are you trying to create json from column values from the database? (also: if you're returning json, claiming "text/html" seems odd, and you should have some `using` statements (not directives) in there)

Comment: Side note: Use parametrized queries to prevent from `SQL` injections

Comment: I would like to create json from column values from the database

Comment: Your title and your question do not match, very confusing. Where is the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get json result from `reader.Read()` method. And you even do not need such behavior.

Wrap you database rows in concrete class and then just serialize your object to json using JSON.NET library

http://james.newtonking.com/json

Look at it's documentation: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html

**EDIT**

```
public class T1 {}
public class T2 {}

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
{
    object data = null;

    string tablename = context.Request.QueryString["tablename"];
    if(tablename == "T1")
    {
        data = LoadTable1Data();
    }
    else if(tablename == "T2")
    {
        data = LoadTable2Data();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Unknown tablename: " + tablename);
    }

    string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    context.Response.Write(jsonData);
}

public List<T1> LoadTable1Data()
{
    List<T1> list = new List<T1>();

    ...
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        list.Add(new T1()); // fill T1 object with row data
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: The problem is my DB columns change per table

Comment: You may create a wrapper class for each table. And return a complex object in json format

Comment: How do I wrap my database rows in concrete class?

Comment: I get this Error 40 The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly

Comment: @JamesJGarner VisualStudio should suggest you to add namespace `System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67220/discussion-between-jamesjgarner-and-jessejames).